# CS50 blur filter showing black image

Tags: c, cs50

I was working on the cs50 blur filter problem (pset 4). I cannot get it working for the life of me- it just shows black every time.

This is the code I tried:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE image_copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            image_copy[j][i] = image[j][i];
        }
    }
    double red_val;
    double blue_val;
    double green_val;
    int blurredpx;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            red_val = 0;
            blue_val = 0;
            green_val = 0;
            blurredpx = 0;
            for (int a = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                for (int b = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                {
                    if (j + b > 0 && j + b < width && i + a > 0 && i + a < height)
                    {
                    red_val += image_copy[j + b][i + a].rgbtRed;
                    blue_val += image_copy[j + b][i + a].rgbtBlue;
                    green_val += image_copy[j + b][i + a].rgbtGreen;
                    blurredpx++;
                    }
                }
            }
            red_val /= blurredpx;
            red_val = lround(red_val);
            blue_val /= blurredpx;
            blue_val = lround(blue_val);
            green_val /= blurredpx;
            green_val = lround(green_val);
            image[j][i].rgbtRed = red_val;
            image[j][i].rgbtBlue = blue_val;
            image[j][i].rgbtGreen = green_val;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any advice?

(this is the "filter-less" assignment)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with this code.

```
            for (int a = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                for (int b = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                {
```

The "nested" inner `for()` loops do not use the loop counter variables correctly

```
            for (int a = -1; a <= 1; a++) // notice 'a'
            {
                for (int b = -1; b <= 1; b++) // notice 'b'
                {
```

Consider that `i` corresponds to `width`, and `j` to `height`.

```
if (j + b > 0 && j + b < width && i + a > 0 && i + a < height)
```

There's a mixup here, corrected below:

```
   if (j + b > 0 && j + b < height && i + a > 0 && i + a < width)
// or (better):
// if (i + a > 0 && i + a < width && j + b > 0 && j + b < height) // width "major", height "minor"
```

Also, it's okay to access the *0th* elements (along the top and the left side of the array.)

```
    if (i + a >= 0 && i + a < width && j + b >= 0 && j + b < height) // note ">= 0"
```

C does not have a nomenclature for *between*. However, it is sometimes convenient to write 2 conditionals so that *between-ness* is expressed.

```
    // extra parentheses added for clarity
    if( ( 0 <= (i + a) && (i + a) < width )
    &&  ( 0 <= (j + b) && (j + b) < height ) )
```

Less important is to keep the *scope* of variables minimal. Instead of declaring the accumulators with such far reaching scope, they could/should be (re-)defined as each new source pixel comes into play.

```
//    double red_val;
//    double blue_val;
//    double green_val;
//    int blurredpx;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            double red_val = 0;
            double blue_val = 0;
            double green_val = 0;
            int blurredpx = 0;
```

Also, the accumulators will be summing integer values. It may be faster to use `int` instead of `double` for those variables. BUT, be sure to use a floating point divide to avoid integer division when calculating the average values for each color.

Finally, it is conventional to access 2D arrays *horizontally*, rather than `vertically`. This would be too much of a re-write to include in this answer.

---

**EDIT**
Similar in concept to the *scan lines* of old TV sets, the elements of a 2D array are stored in memory with *horizontal* elements adjacent to each other. Modern CPU's have one or more high speed *caches* that are filled with adjacent memory values when the program reads a particular memory location. Using the high-speed cache(s) for subsequent calculations, instead of a slower memory read, *really* speeds up execution of the program.

As such, when dealing with a 2D array of small elements (like the trio of pixel RGB values) it is best to access *horizontally adjacent* pixels in your `for()` loops. Depending on the size of the cache(s), *many* subsequent pixels will then be retrieved from *high speed cache* instead of using the slower memory access. In code this would be:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) // zip along horizontally adjacent elements
        {
            int val = arr[row][col]; // example only...
```

This is an important consideration in your career as a programmer. It is especially important when trying to establish that career, answering questions on an interview quiz. You want to demonstrate awareness of these sort of "do's & don'ts".

Comment: Flipping the order of the `for` loop pairs is too much?

Comment: Revising the OP code to function correctly (and faster) would be taking away the challenge (learning experience) from the OP... This question appears so-o-o often, a correct "canned" answer could be provided. My sense is to 'guide' the learners, not provide a copy/paste "answer"... :-) Cheers!

Comment: Okay?! But, I'd append more explanation about how the reversal is cache friendly. _In for a penny, in for a pound..._ ;-) Or, at least link to such a question

Comment: "Cache friendly" sails 32,531 feet over the head of those struggling with blur. Though it is a good time to introduce them to the term, so when they reach a point where it matters a year or two from now -- at least they will have heard of "cache friendly" before `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Most cs50 blur questions (seem to) do the traversal order correctly (e.g. `for (row...) { for (col...) }`), but mess up on the 3x3 convolution matrix or image borders or the averaging (or sigh ...). Maybe it's sufficient to make it a "rule" to do this (without re. cache): . Then, later, explain why when asked why (e.g. _I've been told traverse 2D arrays this way, but what's the advantage?_). But, knowing how to 2D traversal using 1D (e.g. `vec[(row * width) + col]`) seems fundamental (to me) and teaches layout w/o re. cache.

Comment: @CraigEstey The analog would be so easy if dot matrix printers were still in abundance. `:-)`

Comment: @CraigEstey I have always agreed that teaching how to do things right -- the first time -- is the best policy. But I also have done quite a bit of teaching in looking at how people learn. The old "Cognitive Taxonomy" of things. I see merit in what both you and Fe203 propose. There is a lot of value in the "doodlebug" approach where you nudge the student into finding a working solution on their own (let the light-bulb come on) and then ask "Is there a better approach that could have been taken?" And this is student dependent -- something this QA format can't expose in a single question.